# how to install old version of express.js

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

How do I install the right version of express and do I have to uninstall 3.x before I install 2.x?

This is the tutorial I am trying to test: http://psitsmike.com/2011/09/node-js-and-socket-io-chat-tutorial/

I used this package.json:

```
{
     "name": "mukhin_chat",
     "description": "example chat application with socket.io",
     "version": "0.0.1",
     "dependencies": {
        "express": "2.4.6",
        "socket.io": "0.8.4"
     }
}
```

and used the following command:

```
npm install -d
```

When I run the app I still get the question: ... are you migrating from Express 2.x to 3.x ...

Comment: Have you checked your node_modules directory to see what version is currently downloaded?

Answer (score 16):

This is pretty easy, to remove the current version of express, just type

```
npm uninstall express
```

Followed by the following command to install a specific version of a package:

```
npm install express@2.x.x
```

Comment: But what if that file is so "old" it  isn't in the registry anymore?

Answer (score 0):

bro you just need to run this command and your version will be updated at any time.

```
npm i express@sepecifc version number
```

for example i was required to use the old version of express so i do like this

```
npm i --save express@3.20.1
```